Custom Payment Gateway in Shopify like razorpay
I want to create Custom Payment Gateway in Shopify like razorpay.
I have knowlage about remix, react, typescript and node js.
Refrence:- https://github.com/RoopkamalDhindsa/shopify-extensibility-payment-customizations
I wnat to develope ICICI payment Gateway, I already developed this in the JAVA, .net, and Python.
please help me, how to build this.

Once you login on shopify, the below link will help you. Probably you need customization with shopify with your own shop.
https://accounts.shopify.com/lookup?rid=828b049d-63cf-41dd-8920-28616034a9c0&verify=1721372398-44Xn7vFO1U7%2FJWYJ3l61KLIiWkpAXQmkj5sBwmhqjho%3D


I need a custom payment gateway like Razorpay in my custom store
